# Update substring of a column

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, where-clause

I have a table within a SQL Server 2008 database called `Meter`. This table has a column called `Name`.

Each entry within the column `Name` has a prefix of the following `ZAA\`. I'd like to change this prefix to `ZAA_` without affecting the rest of the text within the column.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
UPDATE Meter
SET Name = 'ZAA_' + SUBSTRING(Name, 4, LEN(Name))
WHERE SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 4) = 'ZAA\'
```

Edit:

Or as @Damien_The_Unbliever states, to use an index:

```
UPDATE Meter
SET Name = 'ZAA_' + SUBSTRING(Name, 4, LEN(Name))
WHERE Name LIKE 'ZAA\%'
```

**EDIT**

From your comment, try this statement to fix the additional `\`:

```
UPDATE Meter
SET Name = 'ZAA_' + SUBSTRING(Name, 5, LEN(Name))
WHERE Name LIKE 'ZAA_\%'
```

Comment: `Name LIKE 'ZAA\%'` would at least allow an index (if one exists) to find rows to update.

Comment: Didn't really work as expected. The results are now: ZAA_\. I'd like to just display ZAA_. Thanks

Comment: @user2547340 - looks like an off by 1 error. I've updated my answer to include the query you need.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Worked a treat

Comment: This is what worked for me. For MySQL change, `LEN` to `LENGTH`, and the second parameter of `SUBSTRING` is the starting offset, so it should be one more than the number of characters to strip. So, to remove 4 characters, this value would be 5.

Answer (score 3):

MYSQL:

```
UPDATE Meter
SET Name = CONCAT('ZAA' ,'_', SUBSTRING(Name, 4, LENGTH(Name)))
WHERE Name LIKE 'ZAA\%'
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b228/18)**

**Below is the Query which you can try**

```
CREATE TABLE Meter
    ([Name] varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO Meter
    ([Name])
VALUES
    ('ZAA\001')
;


select * from Meter;

Update Meter
   set Name = stuff(Name,4,1,'_')
 Where SUBSTRING(Name, 1,4) ='ZAA' + Char(92);

select * from Meter;
```